# If Maika and Kaho work in the morning, when do they go to the school?

Tags: blend-s

Maika and Kaho both are highschoolers, but they work in the morning. I assume so since when Maika comes to work, she says "good morning" in most of the episodes. It most likely morning than afternoon.

It's confusing as in the first episode itself, Maika doesn't go to school after work and instead went to an arcade.

Watching the last episode, I'm more or less convinced they work in the morning as Maika and the manager bump into each other at the train station and the time shown on the board was 10:23 AM. So perhaps she goes straight to work after homeroom.

However, in one of the episodes, she did say being held up at homeroom and being late for work. So either Maika was skipping school after doping in for attendance or they have a strange curriculum where they let students do jobs during school hours.

So, when do they go to the school? Don't they have daytime school, or is it evening classes?

Comment: Well, good question. I don't remember seeing any kind of "open hours" sign and I think most of the time we don't even know what the actual time is. But if I'm not mistaken there were a lot of students among the customers too, so the café might only be open in the afternoon and on weekends.

Comment: That's the thing... when Maika comes to work she says "Good Morning" in most of the episodes. It most likely morning than afternoon.

Comment: @Mafuyu-Chama In some workplaces in Japan it's customary to say "Good morning" (おはようございます) when you come to work, regardless of the actual time of the day.

Comment: Watching the last episode I'm more or less convinced it's morning as Maika and Manager bump into eachother at the train station and time shown on the board was 10:23 AM. So perhaps she goes straight to work after homeroom. In one of the episodes she did say being held up at homeroom and being late for work. So either Maika was skipping school after doping in for attendance or they have a strange curriculum where they let students do jobs during school hours. ^^'

Comment: That particular scene on the train station might have taken place on a weekend. Also, some schools in Japan have homeroom at the end of the school day, so she might have attended all classes and still be late to work because of homeroom.

Comment: Yeah, possible. The last scene in last episode is similar to scene in first episode where she bumps into Manager around 10 AM as well. I thought it might be a weekday since she was wearing her school uniform in both scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I've watched a bunch of episodes from the anime and **it was never explained why.**

---

In fact, here are some possibilities that I could think of:

1. **They may have left school for work after dropping in for attendance,** like how you have guessed.
2. **It may not have been morning.** Sometimes in Japan, it is quite common to say "Good morning" when you get to work, regardless of what the actual time of the day is.